# How to get highlighted text in Marklogic Server

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to search a text in a document (doc, docx or pdf) uploaded in Marklogic Server and I want to show that search term highlighted with a color. Suppose a document contains a line "This is a test document" and I am searching for "test" then the line "This is a test document" should be returned with the word "test" highlighted with a color. And if there are multiple sentences containing the word "test" then all those lines should get returned having the word "test" highlighted with a color(e.g blue color). I want to show all those lines with some space or a full stop between them or all results should come in a new line.

And if the sentence is very long then I do not want to show the full sentence in the result. I want to truncate the sentence (say 100 words before the matched word). I know I can use cts:highlight to do this. But I am not being able to get it working. I want the working xquery code.

Comment: you *cant* truncate a sentence with cts:highlight   ...use fn:substring

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via cts:highlight(). See http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/apidocs/SearchBuiltins.html#cts:highlight